# Does anyone know of a story where animals are locked in cages that are actually their spines?

Tags: story-identification

The story is about astronauts arriving on a planet where there is a line of animals locked in their cages. As the astronauts try to free them by cutting into the cages, the animals die. Eventually the astronauts discover that the cages are the animals' backbones.

Comment: Do you have any other details to add? Where you read this, the language, when you read it?

Answer (score 5):

This is a story by Roland Topor. I am not sure what either the original French or English titles are; in Polish translation it is called "Wybawcy" ("The Saviors"). I have read it in Topor's short stories anthology *[Four Roses for Lucienne](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1029103.Four_roses_for_Lucienne)* (though it might also and/or instead be included in the collection "Stories and Drawings"; I am not sure whether the content of different language editions is the same). Polish version of the full text can be found [here](https://www.wykop.pl/wpis/53845443/roland-topor-wybawcy-dziwny-widok-roztoczyl-sie-pr/) and [here](http://rolers.czuby.net/rhp/lirykaepikadramat/t-topo-wybawcy.html).

Comment: Based on the stories by Topor listed on the ISFDB, I suspect the original French title is "Les libérateurs".